# How to View All Related Labels Without URL Posted in Blogspot

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogspot

I have a music website. On those sites, I would like to add to the search menu by category (the first name of the artist).

**For example, in one article, there are two labels, namely:**

Label: A, Avril

Label: A, Avenged

Label: A, Adele

Label: B, BoyBand

Label: B, beyound

Label: B, Bradley

Other ..

How to display the label name `Avril`, `Avenged`, and `Adele` when site visitors open `label A` (`domain.com/a.html`).
Or display the label `boyband`, `beyound`, and `Bradley` when visitors open `label B` (`domain.com/b.html`).

What I mean here only show label name only, not link the article.
Is there a way to use jQuery, JavaScript, or other methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a GET method to fetch data you need.
How you are maintaining data ?

Comment: for example, how?